Headlight mount on straight, high-vibration handlebar
I want to mount a headlight on my handlebar. The handlebar is straight. I have tried a variety of standard bike headlights. These typically come with a quick-release feature. In my usage, which involves high vibration, the quick-release feature eventually allows these lights to shake loose and land on the pavement.
I'm not sure whether my usage involves more vibration than mountain biking. The vehicle in question is actually a Razor push scooter (a/k/a kick scooter - not a footbike, not electric), used on city streets. Its polyurethane wheels and aluminum frame provide no shock absorption. I haven't had this problem with street biking.
If I find a solution to the self-release problem, there may also be a problem of the vibration gradually rotating the light out of position, so that it is pointing up at the sky or down at the ground. The vibration can be pretty bad. It has defeated attempts to control rotation via self-adhering rubber pads.
In the meantime, I do wear a headlamp on my bike helmet. I'd rather have two lights, both for illumination and as a backup. The handlebar is at a good height to minimize shadows.

VHB double sided tape (Unless you want to be able to remove it later)...

Use bike lights that have a clamp-on plastic or metal fitting, and not those that use an elastic band wrapped around some hooks on the light.
From https://www.evocycles.co.nz/Product/358250/on-bike-tools 
This one happens to be a go-pro style of mount, of which there are many, as long as the light has the matching attachment or can be adapted.
If they still slide, then add a small piece of double-sided tape between clamp and bar.  Either thin celulose version or the slightly thicker foam tape.
Another alternative is to hang your light under the bar rather than clamping it on top.
Also have a good look at the front of your ride - is there anywhere on the "headtube" that could take a bolt-on fitting?  Something like:

Ideally you don't want the light down near the wheel, its kinda useless.  So another option is a head-light on your helmet.  This may or may not be legal in your location.  Also, consider the risk to helmet function if it has too much stuff on the outside.

What's the model name/number of the Giant light shown in the image above?

@RayWoodcock no idea - it was intended to be an example of a bolt-on metal clamp.   A right-click and "search image with google" returns  https://www.evocycles.co.nz/Product/358250/on-bike-tools

@RayWoodcock also, it is a common "gopro" style of mount, only just realised.

Thanks. I don't have that right-click option, but I do recall Tineye or some such site will do those searches. Realized after posting the question that Giant was a separate device in that image. Yeah, anyway, the GoPro mount was what I wanted. But wow, $143 for a light on a $40 scooter. It'll be cheaper to just leave it at home and walk.

Closer examination reveals that a problem remains. The bolt-on mount seems likely to prevent the light from rotating on the handlebar. But this light still has the same quick-release feature that causes the light to detach itself from the mount. The $143 light will still land on the pavement.
